# How to redirect the user to a different page using iron router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am redirecting the user to a different page once he click a button using `Router.go('/message');` I want to redirect the user again to the home page after 5 seconds.

Is it possible to do so using iron router package?

Comment: A standard JavaScript `setTimeout` call?

Comment: In Meteor you need to use Meteor.setTimeout - [api docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/timers.html)

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in comments by @ceejayoz and @zauber, you can use `setTimeout`.

Since you redirect to a page, render a template and want to redirect after 5 seconds, I'd suggest redirecting in `onRendered` block instead of router.

```
Template.templateName.onRendered(function() {
    Meteor.setTimeout(function () {
        Router.go('/some-route')
    }, 300);
});
```

If what you want to do is do a check then redirect to the right place, you can either use `onBeforeAction` or render/redirect to somewhere without `onBeforeAction` as well.

If this doesn't solve your problem, edit your question with specific details and leave me a comment if you want an example.